# declare a string rather than address

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

```
alt="" src="ftp://192.168.1.17/Chrysanthemum.jpg" 
        style="height: 299px; width: 317px"
```

how do I declare a string rather than address for ftp? i would like to say

```
alt="" src="imagePath" 
        style="height: 299px; width: 317px"
```

how would I declare that in my actual c# aspx.cs code? And in this code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to use the value of a string variable as the `src` attribute, then you will want to do something like this:

```
alt="" src="<%= Server.HTMLEncode(someStringVariable) %>" ...
```

Or if you are on ASP.NET 4:

```
alt="" src="<%: someStringVariable %>" ...
```

Comment: compiler error photopath does not exist in the current context?

Comment: @Garrith: Then the variable does not exist in the context of the page.  It must either be (1) previously declared in the page, or (2) declared as a field/property in the page's codebehind file.  If you are referencing a static field/property on another class, you will have to qualify it with the class name.  Pasting the code where you declare this variable would help.

Comment: `{

            string PhotoPath;

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex];

            PhotoPath = row.Cells[5].Text;

        }`

Comment: protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @Garrith: If that is a method definition, then the `PhotoPath` variable is in a different scope entirely from the page.  You will have to promote that variable to a class-level variable (a field) if you want this to work.  Note that the field will need to be public or protected for it to be accessible from the page markup file.

Comment: @Garrith: Well, promoting the variable to a class-level field should require no other code changes at all, since the names would be identical.  However, this will have to be a design decision that you make based on the structure of your page.

Comment: yup done and done you sir are are awesome! Thanks so much for the help my god lucky I didnt go with my previous coding should have seen it ;)

Comment: @Garrith: You can only place a bounty on a question if it's been open for a day or so with no accepted answer.  Don't worry about it -- I'm here primarily to help, not garner rep points.

Comment: @Garrith: Now that you've managed to get this to work, you can use the same code to point to an ASHX, without giving the client your FTP password.

Answer (score 1):

```
alt="" src="<%=imagePath%>" 
        style="height: 299px; width: 317px"
```